# How to get XML value in Python

Tags: python-3.x, xml, xml-parsing

I'm trying to read XML value from the soap response. Included the response below, I'm trying to read the Bearer token from the below XML. Tried a couple of ways but failed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope
xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<soapenv:Body>
    <ofo:GetToken xmlns:ofo="http://dummyurl.com/xsd/xyz">
        <ofo:Token>Bearer 123sfafweo123</ofo:Token>
    </ofo:GetToken>
</soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Code I tried

```
  import import lxml.etree
 
  # send request to get above response.
  response = requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers)
  root = lxml.etree.fromstring(response.content)
  textelem = root.find('Envelope/Body/GetToken/Token')
  print(textelem)
```

Comment: Show what you tried and how they failed.

Comment: @user29496 Please edit your question and add this attempt there, not in a comment.

Comment: included the code I tried

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original code failed to take into account namespaces. There are a couple of way to approach it. This, for example, should work

```
ns = {"ofo": "http://dummyurl.com/xsd/xyz"}
root.xpath('//ofo:Token/text()',namespaces=ns)[0]
```

or, if you want to avoid dealing with namespaces:

```
doc.xpath('//*[local-name()="Token"]/text()')[0]
```

Output, in either case:

```
Bearer 123sfafweo123
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was able to retrieve the code

Comment: @user29496 Glad it worked for you!